# Google Script: Request failed for https://www... returned code 416. Truncated server

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

This is my code:

```
function myFunction() {
    var test = DocumentApp.openById('someid');
    test.clear();

    var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/google').getContentText();
    test.appendParagraph(html);
}
```

> Request failed for
>   https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/google returned code
>   416. Truncated server

How to fix this? When I set the website as `www.google.com` it works, but fails when I set to `https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/google`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's because crunchbase.com do not allow robot to crawl their site.
To avoid the error in your script you need to add `muteHttpExceptions`parameter to your urlfetch request:

```
  var params = {muteHttpExceptions:true};
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/google',params);
  var html = response.getContentText();
  test.appendParagraph(html);
```

then you'll be able to see the response :

> Pardon Our Interruption
>
> [image: 0]
>
> ## Pardon Our Interruption...
>
> As you were browsing **http://www.crunchbase.com** something about your
>   browser made us think you were a bot. There are a few reasons this
>   might happen:
>
> - You're a power user moving through this website with super-human speed.
> - You've disabled JavaScript in your web browser.
> - A third-party browser plugin, such as Ghostery or  NoScript, is preventing JavaScript from running. Additional
>     information is available in this http://ds.tl/help-third-party-plugins'
>     target='_blank'>support article.
>
> To request an unblock, please fill out the form below and we will review it as soon as possible.
>
> ```
>     <form id="zwxrztubr" method="POST" action="rytxecbxwsecazdrftrytxe.html"
> ```
>
> style="display:none">Ignore: Ignore: Ignore: 
>             
>               First Name
>               
>             
>             
>               Last Name
>               
>             
>             
>               E-mail
>               
>             
>             
>               City
>
> ---
>
> Request Unblock
>           
>           
>             
>               You reached this page when attempting to access http://www.crunchbase.com/organization/google from 107.178.192.142 on
>   2016-08-31 07:38:18 GMT.
>               Trace: E2A843FA-6F4D-11E6-B2D7-9FC6DA1DE14E via c17ee8fd-4346-4832-a021-e5f8124f2861